# Javascript calculation tools is not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a Javascript calculation tools which sometimes work and sometimes don't work. I don't understand why.

Here is my demo tools : http://propertyjungle.com.au/modern-business/tools_check.php

well, In my "Fixed agent cost when selling" tools there are 5 fields :

1) House Sale Price
2) Rate quoted by agent
3) Other Fees

And in "Result" part there are 2 fields:
1) Agent Fees:
2) Reducing the rate the agent is charging by 0.1% will save you

It's showing the result automatically. I mean on keypress.

So When I increment both "House Sales Price" and "Rate Quoted..." then both result fields is showing me **"NaN"**. But it's should be show the value.. e.g:

```
House Sales Price  = 10000
Rated Quoted  = 0.3%
Other Fees = 0 (empty)

Result: 

Agent Fees = 30 (House Sales Prices * Rated Quoted )
Reducing.... = 10 (0.1% of House sales Price)
```

After that If I increment "Other Fees" it's then showing the result but result is wrong. It's should be e.g :

```
Correct Result: 

Agent Fees = 10030 (House Sales Prices * Rated Quoted + Other Fees[increment by 10,000] )
Reducing.... = 10 (0.1% of House sales Price) 

Wrong Result :

Agent Fees = 10030 (House Sales Prices * Rated Quoted + Other Fees[increment by 10,000] )
Reducing.... = 10010.00
```

**Here is my complete code:**

Javascript:

```
    function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pvalue1').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value +=10000
    document.getElementById('pvalue1').value = value;
}

function decrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pvalue1').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value -=10000
    document.getElementById('pvalue1').value = value;
}

function incrementValueO()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('otherFees').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value +=10000
    document.getElementById('otherFees').value = value;
     $('#pvalue1').trigger("change");
}

function decrementValueO()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('otherFees').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value -=10000
    document.getElementById('otherFees').value = value;
}


function toggleIncrement()
{
    var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pvalue2').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value +=0.1
    value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
    document.getElementById('pvalue2').value = value;
     $('#pvalue1').trigger("change");
}

function toggleDecrement()
{
    var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pvalue2').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value -=0.1
    value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
    document.getElementById('pvalue2').value = value;
     $('#pvalue1').trigger("change");
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('#pvalue1').change(function(){
 var agentfee = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100; 
 console.debug( parseFloat(document.getElementById('otherFees').value));
 var otherFees = parseFloat(document.getElementById('otherFees').value);
 var totalOtherFees = agentfee + otherFees;
 $('#pvalue3').val(totalOtherFees);

 var percentagereduce = parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) - 0.1;
 var newvalue = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * percentagereduce / 100; 
 $('#pvalue4').val(newvalue);         
 var takevalue1 = parseFloat($('#pvalue3').val(), 10);
 var takevalue2 = parseFloat($('#pvalue4').val(), 10);
 var finalvalue = takevalue1 - takevalue2;
 var finalvalue = parseFloat(finalvalue).toFixed(2)
 $('#pvalue5').val(finalvalue);
});

  $('#pvalue2').change(function(){


 var agentfee = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100; 
 $('#pvalue3').val(agentfee);

 var percentagereduce = parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) - 0.1;
 var newvalue = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * percentagereduce / 100; 
 $('#pvalue4').val(newvalue);         
 var takevalue1 = parseFloat($('#pvalue3').val(), 10);
 var takevalue2 = parseFloat($('#pvalue4').val(), 10);
 var finalvalue = takevalue1 - takevalue2;

 $('#pvalue5').val(finalvalue);    
});   
   $('#otherFees').change(function(){
 var agentfee = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100; 
 console.debug( parseFloat(document.getElementById('otherFees').value));
 var otherFees = parseFloat(document.getElementById('otherFees').value);
 var totalOtherFees = agentfee + otherFees;
 $('#pvalue3').val(totalOtherFees);

 var percentagereduce = parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) - 0.1;
 var newvalue = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * percentagereduce / 100; 
 $('#pvalue4').val(newvalue);         
 var takevalue1 = parseFloat($('#pvalue3').val(), 10);
 var takevalue2 = parseFloat($('#pvalue4').val(), 10);
 var finalvalue = takevalue1 - takevalue2;
 var finalvalue = parseFloat(finalvalue).toFixed(2)
 $('#pvalue5').val(finalvalue);   
});
});
```

**Html Code:**

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <td>House Sale Price:</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td><input name="pvalue1" class="form-control"  onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Enter Sale Price" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue1?>" id="pvalue1" size="20" required ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onClick="incrementValue()" value="+" /><input type="button" onClick="decrementValue()" value="-" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rate quoted by agent:</td>
    <td>%</td>
    <td><input name="pvalue2"  class="form-control" onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Percentage" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue2?>" id="pvalue2" size="20"  required ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onClick="toggleIncrement()" value="+" /><input type="button" onClick="toggleDecrement()" value="-" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Other Fees</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td><input name="otherFees" class="form-control"  onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Enter Sale Price" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue1?>" id="otherFees" size="20" required ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onClick="incrementValueO()" value="+" /><input type="button" onClick="decrementValueO()" value="-" /> </td>
</tr>

</table>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 <input name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Calculate" style="color:white;font-size:20px;" class="btn btn-primary">

<br><br>
<h2>Results</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Agent Fees:</td>
<td>$</td>
<td><input name="pvalue3"  onkeypress="validate(event)"  class="form-control"  placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue3?>" id="pvalue3" size="10" class="resultfield"  ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><span id='show-me'  class="form-control" style='display:none'><input name="pvalue4" placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue4?>" id="pvalue4" size="10" class="resultfield"  ></span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Reducing the rate the agent is charging by 0.1% will save you: </td>
<td>$</td>
<td><input name="pvalue5"   onkeypress="validate(event)" class="form-control"  placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue5?>" id="pvalue5" size="10" class="resultfield"  ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Many Thanks to you.

Comment: add console.log lines and see where you are getting the wrong value from the form. You can also add break points and walk through the code. It is also weird how you mix jQuery and getelementById

Comment: @epascarello I'm sorry about my code because I'm new in web development. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var agentfee = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100; 
console.log($('#pvalue1').val());  //3
console.log( $('#pvalue2').val());  // ""
```

`parseInt("")` is NaN

You deal with isNaN in the code above, implement the same logic here.

Comment: Exactly how you solved it when you add and subtract 1000